# triangle twice too big for mesh blueprint

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5, procedural-generation, unreal-blueprint, blueprint

I don't understand why the triangles covering my mesh are twice too big[image: the result that i get now]

Here's my blueprint
main function calling the mesh and the triangle function:
[image: main function]

the mesh function which is supposed to work fine:
[image: the mesh function]

the triangle function which produce triangle twice too big:[image: triangle function]

Comment: perhaps https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask this?

Comment: i didn't know this forum i've just send it there now ^^